# registering a javascript file from a master page

Tags: asp.net, javascript, master-pages

Is there any reason why registering a javascript file from the head tags of an ASP.NET master page wouldn't work? For example, I have the following (plus many other) file referece:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
```

but jquery (and every other JS reference) doesn't work when the page loads.

Any thoughts? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that doesn't work, you can try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%# ResolveUrl("~/js/jquery/jquery-1.4.2.min.js") %>"></script>
```

and in your Page Load handler in the master page add this code:

```
Page.Header.DataBind();
```

Comment: Thanks. Page.Header.DeataBind() throws and object reference exception.

Comment: Sorry, needed head runat="server". Made your suggested changes but the original problem remains...

Comment: Does your js folder actually sit on the web root?  Are you experiencing this in the dev server from Visual Studio or after deploying? (or both?)

Answer (score 2):

The src attribute is relative, try

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
```

and see if that fixes your problem

Comment: Good catch but that wasn't it (I had that before but must have removed the "/" when I was playing with code or cutting and pasting). Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The masterpage can have script resources just like a normal HTML page; you'll probably want to check the problem with an HTTP debugger like [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/) or [Fiddler2](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/), if [phsr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3151632/registering-a-javascript-file-from-a-master-page/3151645#3151645) is correct you'll see the requests failing with an ErrorCode.

Answer (score 0):

Using master pages will not affect the loading of JavaScript files. Your problem is either the location of the file or the script tag is formatted incorrectly.