# Issue with jQuery plugin and ASP.NET content pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, css

I am having trouble using a jQuery called [Tiny Circleslider](http://baijs.nl/tinycircleslider/)! with asp.NET content pages.
I am using a masterpage.

This is in the head of the content page:

`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"    type="text/javascript"></script>`

`<script src="js/jquery.tinycircleslider.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

This is the HTML markup in the contentplaceholder:

`<div id="rotatescroll">
        <div class="viewport">
            <ul class="overview">
                <li><a href="http://www.baijs.nl"><img src="images/hdr3.jpg" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.baijs.nl"><img src="images/hdr2.jpg" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.baijs.nl"><img src="images/hdr1.jpg" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.baijs.nl"><img src="images/hdr4.jpg" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.baijs.nl"><img src="images/hdr5.jpg" /></a></li>

            </ul>
        </div>`

And finally the script itself (at the bottom at the body contentplaceholder):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#rotatescroll').tinycircleslider({ interval: true, snaptodots: true });
    });
</script>
```

I have tried loading the jquery and js into the masterpage with no difference. I added a check if the plugin is being loaded and it is. It just isn't launching for some reason.

With the chrome f12 I got this:

`Error in response to storage.get: TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetHeight' of null
    at StorageInMemory.ChromeStorage.init (chrome-extension://cccpiddacjljmfbbgeimpelpndgpoknn/lib/au.min.js:1:2503)
    at chrome-extension://cccpiddacjljmfbbgeimpelpndgpoknn/lib/au.min.js:1:17570
    at chrome-extension://cccpiddacjljmfbbgeimpelpndgpoknn/lib/au.min.js:1:15137
    at Object.<anonymous> (chrome-extension://cccpiddacjljmfbbgeimpelpndgpoknn/lib/au.min.js:1:17907)
    at require (chrome-extension://cccpiddacjljmfbbgeimpelpndgpoknn/lib/au.min.js:1:627)
    at Object.<anonymous> (chrome-extension://cccpiddacjljmfbbgeimpelpndgpoknn/lib/au.min.js:2:4680)
    at require (chrome-extension://cccpiddacjljmfbbgeimpelpndgpoknn/lib/au.min.js:1:627)`

`Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'tinycircleslider'`

Anyone have any suggestion as to what to do?

Comment: I would venture to guess the reference to the jquery.tinycircleslider.min.js file isn't correct.  see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3151632/registering-a-javascript-file-from-a-master-page

Comment: I had a look at those answers, and tried them all to no avail. Can I provide more information in order for you to better answer?

Comment: By the way, the path of the js is:
root/js/jquery.tinycircleslider.min.js

I have also tried other jquery plugins, but none work.

Comment: You're sure the reference to the javascript file is in the content(aspx) page and not the master page?  I created a project, added your code, and it worked for me.  I did get a different error because you're missing three div's after your list but I'm assuming you included only part of the code.  But if I move your js reference to the master page I get the same error you included.

Comment: Yeah, I am sure. I can provide a live link here:
http://balder.ucn.dk/1020613/about-me.aspx

Comment: I found the problem. For some reason I had hidden a reference to the jquery on the masterpage as well. I removed it, and everything works fine.
Thank you for your effort :)

Comment: cool.  on the network tab of dev tools in Chrome I also saw an error relating to jquery-1.10.2.min.map not found... not sure what that's all about

Comment: Yeah, that's all taken care of. Everything works beautifully now :)

Answer (score 2):

I, too, was encountering weird JavaScript errors and finding `chrome-extension://cccpiddacjljmfbbgeimpelpndgpoknn` in my console. I looked through my extensions and found that `cccpiddacjljmfbbgeimpelpndgpoknn` is the ID for [SmoothScroll](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/smoothscroll/cccpiddacjljmfbbgeimpelpndgpoknn). I disabled that and the error went away.

I don't know if that will fix your problem, but I hope it helps!